# R: Error: object ‘windows’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'

Tags: r

I am testing an R package on GitHub with different operating system. The windows tester works, but the Ubuntu tester throws this error and stops the execution.

> R: Error: object ‘windows’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'

With R 4.3.1.

I don't call windows() anywhere though.

### Traceback

```
Error: Installation failed.
See ‘/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/RtmpkuDi7E/file70d95f7b4613/digestR.Rcheck/00install.out’ for details.
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR, 1 NOTE
See
  ‘/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/RtmpkuDi7E/file70d95f7b4613/digestR.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.

── R CMD check results ────────────────────────────────────── digestR 0.1.0 ────
Duration: 18.6s

❯ checking whether package ‘digestR’ can be installed ... ERROR
Error:   See below...

❯ checking package dependencies ... NOTE
  Depends: includes the non-default packages:
    'dplyr', 'ggplot2', 'ggridges', 'Rcpp', 'tcltk', 'tcltk2',
    'magrittr', 'future', 'biomaRt', 'futile.logger', 'shiny'
  Adding so many packages to the search path is excessive and importing
  selectively is preferable.

── Install failure ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

* installing *source* package ‘digestR’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning messages:
1: package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
3: package ‘ggridges’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
4: package ‘magrittr’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
5: package ‘biomaRt’ was built under R version 4.1.2 
Error: Error: object ‘windows’ is not exported by 'namespace:grDevices'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘digestR’
* removing ‘/private/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/RtmpkuDi7E/file70d95f7b4613/digestR.Rcheck/digestR’

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 1 note ✖
Error: Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

### DESCRIPTION

```
Package: digestR
Type: Package
Title: DigestR Package for Data Digestion
Version: 0.1.0
Author: John Doe
Maintainer: John Doe <johndoe@example.com>
Description: 
    This package provides functionalities for data digestion, visualization, 
    and transformation. It integrates seamlessly with popular data visualization 
    packages and offers additional tools for advanced analysis.
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
biocViews:
Depends: 
    R (>= 3.5.0),
    dplyr,
    ggplot2,
    ggridges,
    Rcpp,
    tcltk,
    tcltk2,
    magrittr,
    future,
    biomaRt,
    futile.logger,
    shiny
Suggests:
    testthat,
    knitr,
    rcmdcheck,
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: Can you point to the package source? It's going to be hard to help without any sort of reproducible example.

Comment: This function is only available on Windows OS installations of R; any package that hard-codes the use of the `grDevices::windows()` function is hard-coding OS-dependence. I don't know why it would be advantageous to do that, but you should be able to replace it with `grDevices::x11()` (linux) or `grDevices::quartz()` (macos). (In fact, `x11()` works just as well on Windows too, though `windows()` includes a lot of checks immaterial on other OSes.)

Comment: Since you said you cannot find it in that repo, look at all of the `Imports:` and `Suggests:` of this package to see what it relies on. Arduously, you'll need to check each dependency (possibly recursively if you see nothing) to see what could be doing this.

Comment: I don't use windows() anywhere.

Comment: It is also not included in Imports or Suggests.